# P20 from A Beautiful Journey through Olympiad Geometry

Tags: geometry

> Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral such that $∠BCA + ∠CAD = 180°$and $AB = AD + BC$. Prove that $∠BAC + ∠ACD = ∠CDA$
>
> Source: Serbia 2014, Opstinski IA

I was able to solve this using Trigonometry and Solution of Triangle but I am unable to find a synthetic solution. Any hints or suggestions are welcome

[image][image]

Comment: Please include your trigonometric solution. It may provide a jumping-off point for a synthetic solution without people duplicating your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Find a geometric transformation that simplifies the conditions.
Naively / with wishful thinking:

1. Something becomes a straight line
2. Two line segments have equal length.
3. Two angles are placed side by side.
4. Two angles are equal.
5. 2 and 4 suggest that there's an isosceles triangle.

---

> Reflect $D$ about the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ to point $D'$.

Show that the conditions imply that $BD'A$ is an isosceles triangle.

Hence, the statement follows.

$$\angle BAC + \angle ACD = \angle BAC + \angle CAD' = \angle BAD' = \angle BD'A = \angle CDA.$$

Answer (score 1):

[image: Diagram for solution.]

It is given that ${\angle BCA}+{\angle CAD}=180°$.

Consider $\triangle ABC$. ${\angle CAB}+{\angle ABC}={\angle CAD}$. $(1)$

It is given that AB=AD+BC.

Let 'M' be on AB such that AM=AD and MB=BC. So, ${\triangle AMD}$ and ${\triangle MBC}$ are isosceles.

Therefore, ${\angle BAD}+{\angle ABC}=360°-2({\angle ADM}+{\angle  BCM})=2{\angle CMD}$

And, form (1), ${\angle BAD}+{\angle ABC}=2{\angle DAC}$

So, ${\angle CMD}={\angle DAC}$

So, AMCD is cyclic.

So, ${\angle BAC}={\angle MAC}={\angle MDC}$, and,

${\angle ACD}={\angle AMD}={\angle ADM}$

Hence, ${\angle BAC}+{\angle ACD}={\angle CDM}+{\angle MDA}={\angle ADC}$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In figure we have:

$$DA=AE\Rightarrow \overset{\large\frown}{DA}=\overset{\large\frown}{AE}$$

$$\Rightarrow \widehat{DCA}=\frac{\overset{\large\frown}{AD}}{2}=\frac{\overset{\large\frown}{EC}}{2}$$

CF is rotated position of CB such that:

$$CF\bot OC\Rightarrow \angle ACF=\angle ACB=\frac{\overset{\huge\frown}{AEC}}2$$

$$\angle CAD=\frac{\overset{\large\frown}{AEC}}2=\frac{\overset{\large\frown}{AE}}2+\frac{\overset{\large\frown}{EC}}2=\angle DCA+\angle CAB$$